# Edit Excel file on fileserver from gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a requirement to allow users to browse directories on our file server, and allow the users to navigate to an excel file open it, potentially update it and save it.  I have it working. I have 2 gridviews - the first binds to an array of DirectoryInfo and the second binds to an array of FileInfo.  I render the name of the file as a link in the grid, like this:

a href='file:///<%# Eval("FullName") %>' target="_blank"  >'<%# Eval("Name") %>'

When the link is clicked, the excel file is opened within a browser. In order to save, it seems they have to do 'save as...' and it's confusing. Here is where my questions are. What's the difference between opening an excel file within a browser, vs. opening it with excel?  Can I have a link to the file in my grid as above, but cause it to open using the Excel application instead of the browser? Does it matter that the excel files are on a file server? I think my users would be more comfortable editing the file within Excel - not in the browser. How can I accomplish this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the excel file in a browser or with excel is a option set on the user's machine. Open Folder Options find xls file and use the "Browse in same Window" Option. [More Info](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059)

If you use the full UNC path (looks like you are) it shouldn't matter that the files are on the server. Assuming that the users have permissions to the share they should be fine.